# Value of elements of a vector2 floored after putting in an List

Tags: java

I know the question looks stupid and i don't know whats wrong with my code, i have been tying to figure it out what's wrong with it but no success

When i put Vector2s in a List, the values of elements of Vector2s are all floored but it works fine with Arrays.

```
   private Array<Float> generateBorderVertices() {

    Vector2[] _hillKeyPoints = generateTheHills();
    Array<Float> borderVertices = new Array<>();

    List<Vector2> vertices = new ArrayList<>();

    int kHillSegmentWidth = 10;

    for (int i = 1; i < kMaxHillKeyPoints; i++) {

        Vector2 p0 = _hillKeyPoints[i - 1];
        Vector2 p1 = _hillKeyPoints[i];
        int hSegments = (int) Math.floor((p1.x - p0.x) / kHillSegmentWidth);

        float dx = (p1.x - p0.x) / hSegments;
        float da = MathUtils.PI / hSegments;
        float ymid = (p0.y + p1.y) / 2;
        float ampl = (p0.y - p1.y) / 2;

        Vector2 pt0;
        Vector2 pt1 = new Vector2();
        pt0 = p0;
        borderVertices.add(pt0.x);
        borderVertices.add(pt0.y);
        vertices.add(pt0);
        for (int j = 0; j < hSegments + 1; ++j) {


            pt1.x = p0.x + j * dx;
            pt1.y = ymid + ampl * MathUtils.cos(da * j);

            //Using a List. here i put the Vector2s into a List
            vertices.add(pt1);
            //End

            //Using Array
            borderVertices.add(pt0.x);
            borderVertices.add(pt0.y);
            borderVertices.add(pt1.x);
            borderVertices.add(pt1.y);


            pt0 = pt1;
        }
    }
    //While accessing them, they are all floored ?!
    vertices.forEach(System.out::println);

    return borderVertices;
}
```

Comment: You're working on the same instance of `Vector2` in your loop, i.e. you never create a new instance in your loop. I guess something like `pt1 = new Vector2()` at the end should work (or put the line `Vector2 pt1 = new Vector2();` at the top of your loop body).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas it worked, i didn't know, i need to make a new instance everytime.

Comment: What made you think you didn't have to? If you directly set the properties of an instance you change that instance and if you add that instance to a list or array multiple times you'll still have one instance, just multiple references to it.

Comment: @SarKurd Don't edit the word "Solved" into your question's title. Answer your own question instead.

Comment: I just didn't need to do that while i was using Arrays, i got a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [comments on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262822/value-of-elements-of-a-vector2-floored-after-putting-in-an-list#comment67786230_40262822):

> You're working on the same instance of `Vector2` in your loop, i.e. you never create a new instance in your loop. I guess something like `pt1 = new Vector2()` at the end should work (or put the line `Vector2 pt1 = new Vector2();` at the top of your loop body). - Thomas